# Pivot/Transpose data in Coldfusion Query of Queries

Tags: coldfusion

I have a COLDFUSION subquery containing the data to be displayed in an HTML table.

The data needs to be pivoted before displaying. I tried pivoting the subquery but its throwing an error of **'containing ( in subquery'**. After going through various forums, looks like all oracle queries do not work on subqueries. I tried doing this http://www.houseoffusion.com/groups/cf-talk/thread.cfm/threadid:46838 way as well but still the same result.

Although, I have a solution which is very crude of writing different queries on contract, datetime and then looping through each of them to get the values and displaying in HTML.

```
select * from 
(select datetime, contract, VALUE from Q_Table_Data) 
t pivot (max(VALUE) for CONTRACT in ('A', 'B', 'C'.......))
```

Please let me know if there is a better way to do the same.

```
Query Data:

CONTRACT    DATETIME            VALUE
    A   28/02/2014 00:30:00      224
    B   28/02/2014 00:30:00      896.9791123
    C   28/02/2014 00:30:00      -1950.0432
    D   28/02/2014 00:30:00      67.11
    E   28/02/2014 00:30:00      28.81819
    F   28/02/2014 00:30:00      80.40048
    G   28/02/2014 00:30:00      257.4114
    A   28/02/2014 01:00:00      224
    B   28/02/2014 01:00:00      814.3872992
    C   28/02/2014 01:00:00     -1879.6858
    D   28/02/2014 01:00:00      67.09
    E   28/02/2014 01:00:00      29.996185
    F   28/02/2014 01:00:00      79.32327
    G   28/02/2014 01:00:00      277.9678
    A   28/02/2014 01:30:00      224
    B   28/02/2014 01:30:00      791.0937311
    C   28/02/2014 01:30:00     -1761.6632




EXPECTED Data:

    Datetime    A          B           C      D        E           F          G
28/02/2014 0:30 224 896.9791123 -1950.0432  67.11   28.81819    80.40048    257.4114
28/02/2014 1:00 224 814.3872992 -1879.6858  67.09   29.996185   79.32327    277.9678
28/02/2014 1:30 224 791.0937311 -1761.6632  67.05   29.257648   79.97122    271.7564
```

---

Comment: At least one RDBMS, sql-server, has the ability to do pivots using sql to get the results you want.  Look into that.  Otherwise you have to muck about with ColdFusion code which can be done, but I would rather avoid it.

Comment: QoQ's only support rudimentary SQL. Anything more complicated than basic SELECT's usually requires a real DBMS. Which DBMS and version are you using? BTW, always best to include that information with any query questions.

Comment: Thanks Leigh. I'm using Oracle. I'm enhancing the already existing application and wanted to reuse the QoQs for table formation rather than rewriting Oracle queries.